# Extract text only from the parent tag with Requests-HTML

Tags: python-3.x, html-parsing, python-requests-html

I'd like to extract text only from the parent tag using Requests-HTML.
If we have html like this

```
<td>
    <a href="">There</a> <a href="">are</a> <a href="">some</a> <a href="">links.</a> The text that we are looking for.
<td>
```

then

`html.find('td', first=True).text`

results in

`>>> There are some links. The text that we are looking for.`

Comment: Hello Gluck. I would look into beautiful soup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `xpath` expression, which is directly supported by the library

```py
from requests_html import HTML
doc = """<td>
    <a href="">There</a> <a href="">are</a> <a href="">some</a> <a href="">links/</a> The text that we are looking for.
<td>"""
html = HTML(html=doc)
# the list will contain all the whitespaces "between" <a> tags
text_list = html.xpath('//td/text()')
# join the list and strip the whitespaces
print(''.join(text_list).strip())  # The text that we are looking for.
```

The expression `//td/text()` will select all `td` nodes and their text root text content (`//td//text()` would select all text content).